How to design async service communication in kubernetes?
I have 3 replicas of each microservices service1, service2, service3. Service1 is supposed to send a message to service2(with generated request_id) and after successfully getting the response, wait for the callback from the service3. The request\response is linked to the callback, by request_id.
I wanted to implement this communication with reactive flux\mono:
        Mono.fromCallable(() -> request)
            .flatMap(webClient.post(request))
            .doOnNext(..wait for the callback and process it..)

Can u suggest a solution how to properly wait for the callback, keeping in mind that microservices run in k8s cluster, and the callback must be send to a particular pod(app running service1)

This seems both broad and unresearched to me? It may be just me, I am not familiar with Kubernetes.
